# Is it even possible to delete from HTML source once you run a jquery script to remove something

Tags: jquery, html

I have about 5000 html pages and in all of them there is a link that is causing lots of problems.

To fix this issue, I used a program that copied a jquery script into every page to remove the link and replace it with a word:

```
$('#mw-normal-catlinks a:first').replaceWith('Categories');
```

It works perfectly, except I still see the link in my html source code. I understand this was going to happen, but is there anyway my script can also delete from the source itself? I don't want to see it at all.

Maybe there is another way to approach this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Wouldn't it have been smarter to instead use a program that removes the link...?

Comment: Use that same program that copied a link into all 5000 files...to remove the link from all 5000?

Comment: Why not .htaccess?  A program to search and replace text in all 5k pages seems rather excessive. What happens if your link "Categories" causes issues in the future?

Comment: You had me at 5000 html pages....

Answer (score 1):

Not even possible. Javascript runs on the client-side, aka the browser.
You should look into [find](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm) and [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was almost definitely NOT the way to do it. If you had a standard header, or JS file included in all pages, that might be a bit better, but still not much.

Use a tool like [this](http://www.inforapid.de/html/searchreplace.htm) to change it in each file at once.